# preactjs seeing [Object object] instead of link

Tags: javascript, preact

I am using preactjs to create my application. On top of this, I am using kendo grid. Inside the grid, I want to show a hyperlink. if the user clicks on the link, it should change the route. To render the link, i am using preact-router.

Here is the working [fiddle](https://codepen.io/OpenStack/pen/mMOzgZ).

```
let { h, render, Component } = preact; 
// import { ... } from 'preact';

let { route, Router, Link } = preactRouter;
/** @jsx h */


class App extends Component {


componentDidMount() {
       console.log('did mount !');
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    selectable: "multiple cell",
    allowCopy: true,
    columns: [
        { field: "productName",
                template: function(e) {
                   return <link href="/">Home</link>
        } },
        { field: "category" }
    ],
    dataSource: [
        { productName: "Tea", category: "Beverages" },
        { productName: "Coffee", category: "Beverages" },
        { productName: "Ham", category: "Food" },
        { productName: "Bread", category: "Food" }
    ]
});
      };

    render({}, {  }) {
        return (
            <div>
                    <h1>
                        Preact Kickstart
                        <sub>powered by <a href="https://github.com/developit/preact" target="_blank">preact</a></sub>
                    </h1>
                <div id="grid"></div>
                </div>


        );
    }
}




// Start 'er up:
render(<App />, document.body);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not even related to preact.

What you're doing is rendering a kendo grid using via jquery inside a preact component and using a preact component as a template.

One way to fix this is to return a html string:

```
template: function(e) {
    const linkEl = $('<a>')
        .attr('href', '#') // keep the a el but do not redirect to a different page on click
        .text('Home')
        .click((e) => {
             e.preventDefault(); // prevent the original a tag behavior
             route('/'); // this is using the `route` from preactRouter, which is already included at the top of the original file
         });
    return linkEl[0].outerHTML; // access the JS DOM element from jQuery element and get it's full html 
}
```

I've also replaced the `link` (which is a typo, probably should've been `Link`) with `a` tag since there is no `link` element in basic html. Even though the name is wrong, this still works because the JSX transformer will interpret all the lowercase components as string name instead of using the component as a function ([see how Babel compiles it](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=PQKhAIAECsGcA9wAtwmAKHQYwPYDtYAXcAGwEs8BrARnAF5wAecq5AJwFMAzOgImF4A-ABI4Ath0bAWlQZlwFiMgEz0mAGQqV23PgJHjJwTVUFA)). The transformer will generate `h("link", { href: "/" }, "Home")` and the `h` function returns an object which is then rendered as `[Object object]` because this is what happens when you try to convert to a string via `.toString` function. If preact would work in this case, it would render the actual `<link href="/">Home</link>` to the user, which would not have the desired behavior (except if a custom `link` component is defined somewhere else).

You can't return a preact component here because the kendo grid template is expecting a string template. One way would be to convert the preact component to a string, but I'm not sure that's even possible, I have never seen it done and you shouldn't have to.

---

Note: As said, you shouldn't have to be converting little parts of React or React-like to html. I would strongly advise against mixing preact code with jQuery which is rendering the kendo grid in your case. These two libraries are doing the rendering very differently. While jQuery is using the old approach of directly modifying the DOM and replacing the whole subtree, React (and all the implementation, such as preact) are rendering to virtual DOM and then have internal logic which figures out the difference with the actual DOM the user is seeing and display only the minimum difference so it makes the least updates required. With my quick google search, I have found [react-kendo](https://github.com/langateam/react-kendo), but it doesn't seem very popular. There are also some blog posts from the kendo team themselves, but I haven't found any official support. If you want to use preact, try to find the (p)react way of doing it, for your example you could be using something like [react-table](https://github.com/react-tools/react-table) ([official demo](https://codepen.io/tannerlinsley/pen/QpeZBa?editors=0010)). If on the other hand, you want to use powerful UI tools provided by kendo, you would be better off not adding the preact to the mix, it will make things more complex without much benefit or it could even make the whole thing worse.

Comment: Thank you for making some great points. The problem with solution you provided is, it will reload the whole page.On click of the link,  I want to change route, which will only reload  specific section of the page. I tried to return jsx inside the template function but i failed. As a work around, i can add event handler on link click and then call `route()` from preact router. +1 for amazing answer but i cant mark this as answer :)

Comment: @SharpCoder I have updated the answer to include a fix for the problem you had mentioned. Note that this I am still convinced that doing this is very wrong and you should avoid doing this inside react codebase at all costs. I did it the same same as it's in your example, i.e. rendering a link with a route to `/` and `Home` as text inside the element. I assume you know these can easily be changed to whatever you might want to do in your actual code.

Comment: @SharpCoder I have also added a more in-depth explanation of why the `<link>...` part wouldn't work in any case and explained what actually happened in your code and what would happen if preact worked like you've expected.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. The changes you suggest shows the label but does not fire event handler. here is the updated link: https://codepen.io/OpenStack/pen/eEBxJz?editors=0010